# Lose focus from ComboBox with Control + Arrowkeys [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am setting up a worksheet which contains a VBA code that places a ComboBox in whatever cell that i go to that uses Datavalidation.

Whenever i go to a cell that uses datavalidation it enables the ComboBox and moves the ComboBox to my selected cell. When i select a new cell it moves the ComboBox to the new position or if the cell does not contain DataValidation it is hidden away.

The problem is i have about 1000 rows and 2 columns that i easily want to navigate through and all of i will be inputting any of the list-options that i use for my datavalidation. Therefor i would prefer to be able to navigate up and down in my rows and right and left between the columns withot using my mouse.

Right now i am unable to do that. When i go to the ComboBox it automaticly lets me type in it and if i then continue to press the arrowkeys i just scrolls through my ComboBox list.

I have succecfully added a code that lets me press enter to go down and tab to go right, but it dosnt work if i change the button to one of the arrowkeys and i am unsure how to edit it so i can go up or left. Without that code i can only use "exit" or a mouseclick to unfocus from that cell.

My prefered solution would be to add an if statement somewhere in the code that requeires me to hold to Control or something to move around without activating the code. For example

Activate ComboBox code
 IF Control is not pressed
 And IF Current Cell contains Datavalidation.

This is the code i am using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice: 2018/9/21
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr

    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
            End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nice code.

Second, try the following in your KeyDown method:

```
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim celltemp(1) As String

    Select Case KeyCode

        Case 38
            celltemp(0) = Application.ActiveCell.Cells(0, 1).Address
            celltemp(1) = CStr(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(0, 1).Value)

        Case 40
            celltemp(0) = Application.ActiveCell.Cells(2, 1).Address
            celltemp(1) = CStr(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(2, 1).Value)

        Case 39
            celltemp(0) = Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 2).Address
            celltemp(1) = CStr(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 2).Value)

        Case 37
            celltemp(0) = Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 0).Address
            celltemp(1) = CStr(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 0).Value)

    End Select

    TempCombo.Enabled = False

    ActiveSheet.Range(celltemp(0)).Activate

    If CStr(ActiveCell.Value) <> celltemp(1) Then _
    ActiveCell.Value = celltemp(1)

    TempCombo.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

I think it has the expected behavior.

As you can see, in my keyboard KeyCodes for arrows are from 37 to 40. I'm not sure it is the same in all keyboards, but you can simply adapt it to make it work. Use the following before the Select Case statement to get your codes in case they were different than mine:

```
debug.print KeyCode
```

If you want that to excecute only while pressing control key, there is a way to do that: using virtual keys, and including inside the KeyDown method an iteration that allows the rest of the code to excecute only while pressing the key you want (in that case: the control key).

There is the way I did it (I'm including full code here):

```
'declare virtual key event listener ---------------------------------------

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------

'declare virtual key constants -------------------------------------------

Private SWITCH As Boolean

Private Const VK_CTRL = &H11 'CONTROL key
Private Const VK_LEFT = &H25 'LEFT ARROW key
Private Const VK_UP = &H26 'UP ARROW key
Private Const VK_RIGHT = &H27 'RIGHT ARROW key
Private Const VK_DOWN = &H28 'DOWN ARROW key
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------

'For more information about virtual key interactions with VBA visit the following link:
'    https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/GetAsyncKeyState-vba-to-wait-until-a-key-is-pressed/


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr

    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")

    With xCombox

        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False

    End With

    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then

        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = RIGHT(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub

        With xCombox

            .Visible = True

            If Not SWITCH Then

                .LEFT = Target.LEFT
                .Top = Target.Top

            End If

            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr

            If .ListFillRange = "" Then

                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr

            End If

            .LinkedCell = Target.Address

        End With

        xCombox.Activate

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If Not SWITCH Then

        Do While GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CTRL) <> 0

            If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 0).Address).Activate
                Exit Do

            ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(1, 2).Address).Activate
                Exit Do

            ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(0, 1).Address).Activate
                Exit Do

            ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Application.ActiveCell.Cells(2, 1).Address).Activate
                Exit Do

            End If

        Loop

    Else

        SWITCH = False

    End If

    If keycode = 17 Then SWITCH = True

End Sub
```

You can download the full file here: [Key-controlled ActiveX comboboxes--test--(GitHub)](https://github.com/Ferd656/Key-controlled_ActiveX_comboboxes--test--)

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for your response Ferd, unfortunately it does not work as intended.

The code that i linked above is not written by me so i cant take credit for that. Tho i tried exchanging my KeyDown code for yours but whenever i go back and tries to type into the ComboBox again i get an error. "Runtime error 1004".

When i troubleshoot it this line is highligted.


    ActiveSheet.Range(celltemp(0)).Activate

If i dont make any changes to it - it inacitvates the ComboBox and it wont activate again.

Comment: _celltemp_ is just an array containing 2 values: new cell's address(stored in _celltemp vector 0_) and new cell's value(stored in _celltemp vector 1_). So, what `ActiveSheet.Range(_celltemp(0)_).Activate` is doing is passing the address(as a string) as the new range(cell) to be activated afted pressing the arrow keys. For example, imagine that the value stored in _celltem(0)_ is "A1", then, the cell A1 is the one that will be activated by the process.

Comment: If the error persists, try one of these solutions: **#1** Make sure you're properly declaring the _celltemp_ array with `Dim celltemp(1) As String`. **#2** Use 2 separated variables instead of the _celltemp_ array: one variable instead of _celltemp(0)_ and other differente variable instead of _celltemp(1)_, **#3** Another option is to use the _offset_ method instead of directly indicating a range to be activated. The code is there for you to adapt it to the style which you feel most comfortable with. Do some tries and and feel free to share your results here.

Comment: I left at the bottom of the answer a link to the _GitHub_ repository where I saved the .xlsm file that contains the code we are working on this topic. You can take a look to that file for reference, if you want.